# Why does my laptop restart instead of waking up after resuming from suspend?

Tags: 10.10, suspend, restart

My laptop is a Vaio VPCF11M1E, running Ubuntu 10.10 64-bit.

After being suspended, I press the power button to wake it up, but it restarts the machine and I lose all my work. I do not have the same issue under Windows.

But hibernating works.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me on Ubuntu 10.10 before I installed ATI drivers

Edit the file `/etc/default/grub` (as root)

Change the line with:

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

to:

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_sleep=nonvs"

run `update-grub` (as root).

This worked just fine after installing the ATI drivers:

> I've solved a similar issue (reboot on resume) with a Sony Vaio VGN-FW51ZF by changing the last line of the file `/etc/acpi/sleep.sh` from *pm-suspend* to *pm-suspend --quirk-radeon-off* (guess it was a problem related with ATI proprietary drivers)."

So thanks for those tips and I hope this save you some time. I'm about to do the same on my Ubuntu 11.10 I'll let you know if it worked!

---

Did not worked on Ubuntu 11.10 it still reboots instead of resuming :(

https://askubuntu.com/a/64408

Comment: Answer worked perfectly with my Medion E7214 on Ubuntu 11.10. Thank you for helping.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** We're very sorry, but this is not a good place to put another question as the only people seeing your "answer" will be the original poster and a bunch of reviewers trying to review your "answer" for quality...  So please first look over the existing answers and if none of them work, [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) and refer back to this question and explain what went wrong.  **;-)**

Answer (score -1):

If you have grub2 you should run `sudo update-grub2` (run both just in case)

Comment: It's not necessary to run `sudo update-grub2` if you're running `sudo update-grub`. `update-grub2` is just a symlink to `update-grub` (`$ file $(which update-grub2)` `/usr/sbin/update-grub2: symbolic link to 'update-grub'`). Running `update-grub2` in a system that only has GRUB2 (including Ubuntu 9.10 or later) will *always* be equivalent to running `update-grub`.